# How to determine if a Publishing Page in Sharepoint 2007 is actually published

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Within a web part code I have got to transform a sharepoint website in a pdf document, I have completed this.  There is an extention that needs to be done, where the PDF document is to only get the published pages.

So I have a list of pages using the "siteMapnodeCollection" and getting the child nodes etc, how do I check that the publishing page represented by a node is actually published & approved?

Thanks

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PublishingPageCollection pages = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web).GetPublishingPages();
foreach (PublishingPage page in pages)
{
    if(!page.ListItem.File.Level == SPFileLevel.Published)
       return;

    // logic
}
```

You can also pass a CAML Query in the GetPublishingPages() method, bringing the items under the correct status.

Answer (score 3):

See:

- `Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingPage.IsPublishingPage(listItem)`
- `Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(listItem)`

and:

- `(pageinstance).ListItem.File.Level (should be "Published")`
- `(pageinstance).ListItem.ModerationInformation.Status (should be "Approved")`

**update:**

Most publishing webs are configured to use moderation, but yours may not so you might not have to check for approval.